# How to run Typescript files

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've recently been asked to edit the CSS that is used by a .tsx file.

I've worked with html, javascript, and css, and currently learning NodeJS, but I don't know anything about Typescript.  I've tried to follow the steps seen here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html but I don't really follow it and I can't get anything to run.  Most directions I find are for creating a brand new project, but nothing about running an already made project you cloned from Git.

I just want to run this project's home page so that I can edit the SCSS file and view my changes before sending them back the updated SCSS.  But I can't figure out how to do this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Assuming everything's been set up for this project and you just need to make edits there's probably run scripts you can use.  Without knowing what your project looks like, it's impossible to say.

Comment: You probably need to run `tsc` to compile your Typsescript files to Javascript files that you will be able to run.

Comment: Would it hurt to ask how to build and test your changes? This seems like a question for a colleague, not stackoverflow.

Comment: @Thom thanks, I tried that and it produced a JS file, but while trying to run it through node it's producing "unexpected token" errors on the opening "<" of the first div?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger, thanks for the response, but unfortunately it's not an option because that developer is no longer in contact

Comment: Nobody knows how to build the product? How do you ship it to customers?